# How to deal with OrganizationalUnit with Spring LDAP 2.0 ODM?

Tags: java, spring-ldap

I'm migrating our LDAP client application that manages our OpenLDAP objects. This application is written in Java and currently use spring ldap 1.3.
I'm currently (70%) in the process of migrating to spring ldap 2.0.2 and I'm quite happy with this new version.

I've created our objects and used annotations (@Entry ...) and it works.

Now here is my problem :

- My users are in ou=people,dc=mycompany,dc=com
- The user belongs to an unit
- base name for units is ou=units,dc=mycompany,dc=com
- Units are hierarchically embedded : ou=a,ou=b,ou=units or ou=e,ou=b,ou=units

Here is my code:

```
@Entry(objectClasses={"organizationalUnit", "top"}, base="ou=units")
public class Unit {

    @Id
    private Name dn;

    @Attribute(name="ou")
    @DnAttribute(value="ou", index=1)
    private String rdn;
}
```

But this code only works for first level units !
I've found the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666222) and @marthursson suggests to write its own ObjectDirectoryMapper. Is this the only solution ?

Edit 1 : You mean, like :

```
@Entry(objectClasses={"organizationalUnit", "top"}, base="ou=units")
public class Unit {

    @Id
    private Name dn;

    @Attribute(name="ou")
    @DnAttribute(value="ou", index=1)
    private String rdn;

    @Attribute(name="ou")
    @DnAttribute(value="ou", index=2)
    private String lvl2;

    @Attribute(name="ou")
    @DnAttribute(value="ou", index=3)
    private String lvl3;

    @Attribute(name="ou")
    @DnAttribute(value="ou", index=4)
    private String lvl4;
}
```

I get one IndexOutofBoundException if there is no value to put at index 2. Typically when I'm loading the root unit under ou=units.

Edit 2 : The following function does the job :

```
public String getRdn() {
    LdapName n = LdapNameBuilder.newInstance(dn.getSuffix(dn.size()-1)).build();
    return n.getRdn(0).getValue().toString();
}
```

Comment: You should be able to have separate properties annotated with `DnAttribute`, one for each ou entry in the RDN, just with different indexes.

Comment: BTW, the other question you are referring to does not seem to be related to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: It doesn't work as index is a constant, see edit 1 above.

Comment: I misunderstood your problem slightly in my previous comment, sorry for that.

So the thing you want to do is that for each entry you need to get the hierarchy of ou:s above, right? You can't do that using declaratively, but it's quite simple to do in code. I.e. you can easily create a method `getRdn()` in your class that returns the tree above, e.g. using `LdapName#getPrefix()` with the DN value.

Comment: Could you add an answer so that I can give you credit for the solution ?